# Is it possible to animate navigation title display mode?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, navigationbar

How can I achieve smooth animations when toggling the navigation display mode in SwiftUI? I've tried using the `navigationBarTitle` modifier with the `.large` and `.inline` modes, and while the display mode changes, the animation isn't as smooth as I expected. Here's the code I've been using:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var navigationDisplayMode: NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode = .large

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, SwiftUI!")
                    .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: navigationDisplayMode)
                
                Button("Toggle Display Mode") {
                    withAnimation {
                        navigationDisplayMode = navigationDisplayMode == .large ? .inline : .large
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code toggles between the `.large` and `.inline` display modes when the button is pressed, but the animation isn't as smooth as expected. How can I achieve a smoother animation when transitioning between these navigation display modes?

Answer (score 1):

The navigation bar title is a low-level feature of a navigation hierarchy and I was also not able to find a way to animate a change easily.

I originally posted an answer to show how you could use a `ZStack` to switch between alternative `NavigationStack` views. Using the default transition of `.opacity`, this gave a relatively smooth transition between alternative navigation bar title display modes. But the more I thought about it, the less I liked this solution, so I scrapped it (you can find it in the activity history if you are really interested).

I would suggest, it would be better to hide the navigation bar title and just implement your own dynamic page title. Main advantages of doing it this way:

- there is only one `NavigationStack` in the hierarchy and this is the top level view
- you can animate the title any way you like.

Here is a simple example of how a dynamic page title could be implemented. This emulates a navigation bar title with the different display modes that you were using before:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var largeTitle = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, SwiftUI!")

                Button("Toggle Display Mode") {
                    withAnimation {
                        largeTitle.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar(.hidden)
            .padding(.top, largeTitle ? 80 : 40)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .overlay(alignment: largeTitle ? .topLeading : .top) {
                Text("Title")
                    .font(largeTitle ? .largeTitle : .headline).bold()
                    .padding(.top, largeTitle ? 30 : 10)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of navigation Title Transition. It is supposed to work with animation when a user scrolls through some lengthy content on view. Then it gives space to content, and the title goes to the middle of the Navigation bar. This is the default behavior. I don't see any issues with this Animation. But if you want to achieve when you tap someplace and your Navigation bar title goes with Animation to the top in the middle, you have to write your own custom Navigation bar or some UI that mimics the navigation bar.
I am attaching the video of the iOS simulator that shows its default behavior, which you have posted. I hope this will give you some thought on this.

[image]